# Robocopy: show skipped files and files with an error while copying

Tags: windows, robocopy

I'm using the following command for copying files while preserving timestamps:

```
robocopy [source] [destination] /E /ZB /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T /R:1 /W:5 /V /NFL /NDL /NS /NC /NP /log:"[log-path]" /XD "System Volume Information" "Recycler"
```

Now in the log files I see that there are files skipped or there are errors while copying. But I don't know which file had an error or is skipped.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the skipped and/or errored files reported to the console, perhaps?

Comment: No it is everything in the log file. At this time for example one directory was skipped, but I don't know which? Was it one of my excluded directories? Perhaps it will show some errors if I use full logging, but also there is perhaps an "Access denied" instead of something like "Error: Access denied". I look for some keyword I can search (because looking through all files is too much ...)

Comment: Techie007's answer will show skip reasons in your NEXT run.  (StinkPickle's answer is partial:  robocopy may also not copy files for inadequate file permissions or file types robocopy won't copy.)  Note:  to see differences after the copy -- missing files, etc -- consider WinMerge, and compare the two top folders.  Under the WinMerge's View menu, uncheck "show identical items"; check "show left unique" and "show right unique".  Also, for FASTER comparisons, look under WinMerge's Edit... Options... Compare, and set the "Compare Method" to something other than "Full Contents".

Comment: `/V` should show skipped files, so you'll likely need to play around with your other parameters to determine which one is interfering, but my guess is `/NFL` and/or `/NDL`.  Have you tried adding `/FP`?

Answer (score 5):

SKIPPED via robocopy means that source and target versions of the file are same.. SO, it just skips the copy. You can use /is option to overwrite even the exactly same files.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: @DavidPostill Still useful though, so it's all good.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `/NFL` and `/NDL` arguments from your command line to include file and directory lists in your logs (perhaps consider removing `/NS` and `/NC` as well).

Run it again, and look at the actual file list in the log.

Entries in the log with no status listed to the left of the file/directory name (statuses are like "Newer", "Extra", etc.) are files that were skipped (because they are the same, and therefore  no action was taken).

Comment: So [this source](http://www.elasticsky.de/en/2012/11/robocopy-nur-fehler-loggen/) is wrong?

Comment: That source seems to be aiming to remove all logging except errors.  A skipped file is not an "error". :)

Comment: So should I worry about skipped files? If I interpret it right than skipped files are available on the destination folder...

Comment: Do you know a programm/power shell script/vb script which can show me the skipped files/directories?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I think I know the answer. When I ran it the first time I moved about a gig just to see if my setting were correct. Then I ran it again with for the full copy and it "SKIPPED" the first set of files I moved, but in the log it says "same" however the summary says "SKIPPED".

Answer (score 1):

A way to show the skipped files/folders is with a command line (assuming you had full logging, e.g., `/v`). Substitute your log file name for `RoboCopy.Log` in this example:

```powershell
find /v "New File" RoboCopy.Log | find /v "New Dir"
```

It will narrow down the output so you can spot the skipped file or folder.